# How to make chrome remember the one tab(or a window) information that can be used in other tabs

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In a chrome Extension , How to make chrome remember the tab information that can be used by other tabs.

For example or being more specific., 
I've a button in one of the tabs that when clicked opens another tab and i used chrome.createtabs for this in Background.html. I also created a variable which will save the tab id of the new tab created (say tab1). I want to use tab1 in myscript.js(content script) to place the information in parent tab. So how can i send the request from background.html to content script?

Or Is there any way to post the content to the webpage using background.html?

btw I used localStorage['tab1'] to save the new Tab ID.

Lemme know if i'm not clear. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all described in [Message Passing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/messaging.html) with examples. To send a message from a background page to a content script:

```
background.html
===============
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response.farewell);
  });
});

content_script.js
=================
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension");
    if (request.greeting == "hello")
      sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
    else
      sendResponse({}); // snub them.
  });
```

Comment: Hi Serg,
i'll add more context, 

say there is one tab open (google.com) i've placed a button on google.com using my content script. The Button should create a tab when clicked with url as "cricinfo.com" . Now it redirects to "espncricinfo.com" , So i want this url to be displayed in my original tab. 

Done this
First i sent a request form contentscript to background.html with the url. 
Background.html creates a new tab taking that url.
Send the information from background.html to content script using what u've said.

But Strangely it doesnt work. Can you be more specific now. Thanks

Comment: @Ravi Can you show some code? Maybe starting a new question would be a better idea.

Comment: Hi serg I placed the code with a new question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826263/problem-with-getting-the-tab-id-in-chrome-extension., Can u please look at it